# Monitor power control on touchscreen monitor

Tags: display, power-management

I have a computer (Ubuntu) connected to a touchscreen monitor via a single USB-C cable. It provides video output, touchscreen abilities, and power.

My goal is to have a `systemd` service use `xset` or `xrandr` to disable video output and force the monitor into power-saving mode.

I've tried these manually, just running from a Terminal:

- `xset dpms force off`
- `xrandr --output DP-1 --off`

These work and disable the monitor, forcing it into a "No Signal" state for 60 seconds. After 60 seconds, the monitor seems to realize that something is still connected and reconnects the graphics and it turns back on.

My theory is that the monitor, after the 60 seconds, realizes there is an active input (because the USB-C cable is still providing touchscreen data and power) and turns back on.

Is there any way to have the monitor stay off or is this a lost cause? It is ideal to keep touchscreen functionality (tap to wake back up) but I doubt this is possible, and disabling the touchscreen functionality while asleep would be fine.

Comment: When you use `xset` and `xrandr` directly, you are probably overriding your desktop environment's built-in facilities to control those same features. The 60-second interval might be the result of the desktop environment re-asserting its settings; if so, you should probably communicate with the desktop environment to get the effect you want, rather than trying to compete with it. Or at least disable the desktop environment's related features first before asserting direct control yourself.

Comment: @telcoM That idea makes sense. How might I go about doing that? I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean by "disable the desktop environment's related features"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of poking at the X11 server directly with `xset` and `xrandr`, try using `xdg-screensaver activate`. It tells the desktop environment to activate the screen saver, which will usually cause the display power-saving mode to be enabled, often with a delay of one minute or so (to allow immediate restoration of the screen if it turns out there is someone using it).

If you want to assume direct control of the screensaver features, you might want to disable the desktop environment's screen saver service first. For Ubuntu's default GNOME desktop environment, this would probably be something like:

```
systemctl --user mask org.gnome.ScreenSaver.service
```

I'm more of a KDE guy myself, so my information on GNOME and its particular use in Ubuntu might be out of date or in error. If anyone knows better, feel free to edit this post or make your own.